# How to get the largest value (range 1-2) from column 3 in a 4th column grouped_by the id's in column 1?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I want R to replace all the rows with the same chargepoint_skey and socketsinuse by just one row with that particular chargepoint_skey and socketsinuse. Ofcourse this needs to be done for all the individual chargepoint_skeys. So a kind of summarize. How can I get this done?

My code so far to get the dataframe (see image):

```
vraag_5 <- FACT_CHARGESSESION_JOINDIMLOCATION %>%
             select(ChargePoint_skey, Socket_ID) %>%
             group_by(ChargePoint_skey) %>%
             mutate(Socket_ID = str_replace_all(Socket_ID, "XXXXXX", "0")) %>%
             mutate(socketsinuse = max(Socket_ID))
```

Update after changing code:

[dataframe3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giLQ8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to :

```
vraag_5 <- FACT_CHARGESSESION_JOINDIMLOCATION %>%
                mutate(Socket_ID = as.numeric(stringr::str_replace_all(Socket_ID,
                                   "XXXXXX", "0"))) %>%
                group_by(ChargePoint_skey) %>%
                summarise(socketsinuse = max(Socket_ID, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I think we're on the right direction, because the number of rows have decreased, but I get now this output (see image in my question). Now I want for example for the chargepointskey == 2174 just the one with the biggest socketinuse. And that for all the other chargepointskey's too, how can I get that done?

Comment: @daniël.vandijk Can you try my updated answer. I included only `ChargePoint_skey` in `group_by` so you should have only 1 row for each `ChargePoint_skey`.

Comment: @daniël.vandijk Please ask only one question per post. If you have additional question ask that as a new question.